# how to edit the EditTextPreference in android honeycomb?

Tags: java, android, layout, preferences, android-3.0-honeycomb

i want to edit the `EditTextPreference` in android Honeycomb. by default the `EditTextPreference` shows only one space to input text and 2 `buttons`, OK and Cancel. I want to add one more space to input text. it can be used to input the username and password.

```
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="WEB ALBUM">
            <EditTextPreference
                android:key="default_edittext"
                android:title="@string/title_webalbum01"
                android:summary="@string/login_id_webalbum01"
                android:dialogTitle="@string/dialog_title_webalbum01">       
        </EditTextPreference>       
     </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

how to extend DialogPreference from EditTextPreference? can anybody give some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend [`DialoPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html) with your custom Dialog.

Note that preference UI components were designed to handle one preference key (it knows how to save one value when its edited). In your case you're going to handle two preference keys, so you need to be careful when implementing your custom preference.

Comment: how to extend DialogPreference from EditTextPreference? can anybody give some example?